# TextField swiftUI accepting only time

Tags: swift, swiftui, time, textfield, formatter

I can't find too many examples of the following issue so here I'm again asking for your help, on my app, I want my user be able to input on the textfield only time for example 22:30, the textfield have to accept only time not any kind of letter or other and moreover i need to make sure the user don't insert more than 4 digits is there any possible solution and how can I do that?

```
TextField("Test2", text: $test)
                       .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                       .keyboardType(.numberPad)
```

i have no idea what to look to solve this issue, some sort of formatter but i can only find the number formatter, noting related to time

thanks

Comment: Well I don’t understand a negative vote ..! But thanks to who help to solve this issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
struct TimeTextField: View {
    @Binding var time: String

    var body: some View {
        TextField("Time", text: $time)
            .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            .textContentType(.none)
            .keyboardType(.numberPad)
            .onChange(of: time) { newValue in
                time = formatTimeInput(newValue)
            }
    }

    private func formatTimeInput(_ input: String) -> String {
        let allowedCharacterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789")

        // Remove non-numeric characters
        let numericString = input.components(separatedBy: allowedCharacterSet.inverted).joined()

        // Limit the input to 4 digits
        let limitedString = String(numericString.prefix(4))

        // Insert colons at appropriate positions (e.g., 2230 -> 22:30)
        let formattedString: String
        if limitedString.count > 2 {
            let index = limitedString.index(limitedString.startIndex, offsetBy: 2)
            let hour = limitedString[..<index]
            let minute = limitedString[index...]
            formattedString = "\(hour):\(minute)"
        } else {
            formattedString = limitedString
        }

        return formattedString
    }
}
```

To restrict user input in a TextField to a specific format, such as allowing only time input with a maximum of 4 digits, you can utilize the TextField's textContentType property and validate the input using a custom formatter.

---

for iOS 17 onChange perform call deprecated*

```
.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UITextField.textDidChangeNotification)) { _ in
                time = formatTimeInput(time)
            }
```

Comment: In iOS17 the onChange perform call is deprecated. How should we call formatTimeInput now? Or is there meanwhile a easier way? Thanks for your answer

Comment: .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UITextField.textDidChangeNotification)) { _ in
                time = formatTimeInput(time)
            }

Comment: onChange is only sort of deprecated. The version that is deprecated is the one that has a closure with only the newValue. You now have access to a 0 parameter closure or a two value closure with the old and new value. In other words, you can do
 .onChange(of: time) { oldValue, newValue in
                time = formatTimeInput(newValue)
  }